# Always fitting content on screen vertically using CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have implemented a grid system using Bootstrap that displays some contents. There are no images in the grid. I will have this page open on my screen and the contents on the page can be dynamically added every 5 mins via ajax request. I do not want to scroll through when the content does not fit vertically anymore. Is there a way to use css to set the zoom level or decrease font size to make sure that everything always fit the screen or at least try its best to fit the screen vertically?

Comment: Can you show some code as well?

Comment: Probably, most likely. Would be nice to work with a [reprex], though. `transform: scale(..)`  would be one option. Here's how I did it with an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72702262/2015909).